# Angular General Error Handling for unexpected errors

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Is there a way to set a general error handling behaviour (e.g. to throw a general error message) in case there is anything going wrong with the server? In my project, I send or request data to or from the backend,

```
this.userService.post(this.user).subscribe( (reponse: Response) => {
    if(response.status === 200){
        // success
    }
}, error => this.handleError(error._body));
```

and when there is anything wrong with the data or the user etc., I return a response which includes a individual error message in the body. But when there is an error which isn't thrown intentionally by the backend (e.g. an internal server error 500) I pass the stacktrace up to the user.

It would be better so set a general error message which is displayed in frontend when there is anything *really* going wrong in the backend. How? I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to distinguish in every backend request or post if the error is unexpected or thrown by the backend (if that helps: every error thrown by the backend intentionally have status code 409).

Answer (score 0):

You can use interceptors:

generate a service and implement `HttpInterceptor` interface

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (error.status === 409) {
            console.log('409 ERROR'); <-- gets called on each response
          } else if(error.status === 500) {
           console.log('500 ERROR'); <-- gets called on each response 
          }
        }
        return throwError(error);
      }),
    );
  }

}
```

and then add `HttpErrorService` to your `app.module.ts`

```
    providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpErrorService,
      multi: true
    },
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks! And how do I use it in my case? Does every .ts-class have to have a HttpErrorService in the constructor? Is the intercept-part executed always when the backend sends a response?

Comment: Does every .ts-class have to have a HttpErrorService in the constructor? no

Comment: Is the intercept-part executed always when the backend sends a response? yes

Comment: But every .ts-class which sends backend requests or posts has to have a HttpErrorService in constructor? Then, always when the backend sends a response, the intercept-part is executet, right? Can I pass also the component in which the HttpErrorService is defined?

Comment: the "interceptor" method simply intercept all "request/response" that are made by the client and backend.

Comment: every .ts-class which sends backend requests or posts has to have a HttpErrorService in constructor? no. HttpErrorService does not need to be in any constructor

Comment: but where do I get the return of the intercept-part then? sorry

Comment: I tried but when I add it to the app.module.ts, it says "Cannot find name 'HTTP_INTERCEPTORS'.".

Comment: have you imported "HTTP_INTERCEPTORS"?
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, but now I get "Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'. in the HttpErrorService? What are the methods catchError and throwError?

Comment: what version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: Where can I see that? The angular version is 4.3.6.

Comment: you can see it in package.json file. but default version of ng4 rxjs is probably old for the syntax i sent you. you can either update angular or convert my syntax to the old version

Comment: It's 5.4.3. as well. My problem is that I don't really understand your code, sorry. Why do you use pipe? What are catchError and throwError? Where are they defined?

Comment: You cannot solve your problem without having some basic knowledge of RxJS. and I really don't know another way without using RxJS. in fact I think there is no possible way to solve this problem without RxJS.

Comment: But when I only have `console.log("error service"); return next.handle(req);` in the intercept-part, it doesn't output anything when I force a backend request. But it should, doesn't it?

Comment: to see the log
next.handle(req).subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
also remove the :Observable<HttpEvent<any>>

Comment: I cannot remove the Observable return type because I have to return an Observable when I implement HttpInterceptor. But also with `next.handle(req).subscribe((res) => console.log(res)); return Observable.throw(req);` it doesn't outputs anything...

Comment: In the backend (Java), I send the responses like `Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).entity(Error.WRONG_LOGIN_DATA.toString()).build();` and the request in frontend looks like you can see in the question. So having the HttpInterceptor, the intercept-part should be executed when the backend sends a response, doesn't it? But that's not the case - there isn't any output when I put e.g. a console.log in the intercept-part. That's the main problem.